# Closest H3 above a Table with Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, siblings

I try to select the heading of a table where a class is set. In words: look for an element with the class `.red` and start looking for an `h3` element ABOVE this element.

```js
$('.xred').closest('table').addClass('test').prev('h3').addClass('test');
```

```css
.test { background-color: green; }
.xred { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Goal</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Blabla</td>
    <td class="xred">Red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Works fine, as long I don't put anything in between the table and the H3.

How can I achieve that it will also work when other elements are in between?

```js
$('.xred').closest('table').addClass('test').prev('h3').addClass('test');
```

```css
.test { background-color: green; }
.xred { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Goal</h3>
<div>The Problem DIV</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Blabla</td>
    <td class="xred">Red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why you'd do something so inefficient. Do you not have direct access to the html?

If you do, it might be way easier to do something like this?

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapperdiv>
  <h3>Goal</h3>
  <div>The Problem DIV</div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Blabla</td>
      <td class="xred">Red</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.xred').closest('table').parent().find("h3").addClass("test");
```

Having a wrapper makes it all easier, yeah?

Then again, I would personally never build up anything that I would need to do so much DOM searching. It's wildly inefficient. I'd recommend a good html structure with wrapper divs which you can store in a variable like so:

```
var $wrapperDiv = $('.wrapperDiv');

$('h3', $wrapperDiv).addClass("test");
```

But, that's just me...

**but why?**

Well, whenever you use functions like `prevAll` and `closest`, you're traversing the entire DOM. It makes for quite the CPU usage and often laggy responses on slower devices like cellphones. It also drains their batteries quicker.

Besides this, when stacking function on top of function, you'll notice laggy responses on any device.

The best practice is to store any static wrapper within a variable once, so you don't have to traverse the DOM constantly. Then, using as little selectors as possible to get what you need, because again; every selecting function will once more traverse the DOM. It's just CPU intensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's the way I would do it normally - but the problem here is that I can't edit the code. It's provided by a script and I want only to show how later  - nicely implemented - improvements could look like.

Comment: Hmmm, and there aren't ANY wrappers around both the h3 and the table?
Could you tell me why exactly you want to choose a specific h3? If I know for what type of action you may want to select it, I may be of further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) that select preceding previous element that matched. [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) select previous element if matched parameter.

```js
$('.xred').closest('table').addClass('test').prevAll('h3').addClass('test');
```

```css
.test { background-color: green }
.xred { background-color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Goal</h3>
<div>The Problem DIV</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Blabla</td>
    <td class="xred">Red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with that solution is, that all H3 above the code are selected. But I only want the FIRST after the table. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Thanks! That works amazing when I have one table with only one H3. But how can I change the code, that this works for multiply tables with the same issue? https://jsfiddle.net/wp8e6yxz/1/

Comment: @user1658080 That isn't a good thing to changing question after posted answer. However in that case, you can use `.prev().prev()` to do it. See https://jsfiddle.net/wp8e6yxz/2/

Comment: Sorry.. :) - doing that restricts the possibilities of how many elements can be between the table and the h3. I look for a solution where it looks for the first H3 after a table with the class "red", no matter how many other elements are between the table and h3. And that solution should work for many tables with that case.